# Resetting a carousel after changing tabs?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've got an application set up with 6 tabs in a tabview.
2 of these tabs are Carousels with images in them.

Got 2 problems:

1: When i switch cards inside the carousels, the animation only works from right to left (next slide animation). But when slide from left to right (previous slide animation), the previous image just appears, without animation.

2: When i change tabs to any other tab, and then come back to the carousel, i need it to be resetted to the start position - showing the first image again.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the code im using for the carousels tabs:

```
var Tab1 = {
    id:'Tab1',
    xtype: 'carousel',
    layout: 'card',
    title: 'Product Info',
    iconMask: true,
    iconCls: 'info',
    bufferSize: 5,
    items: [
        { cls: 'card product-info page1' },
        { cls: 'card product-info page2' },
        { cls: 'card product-info page3' },
        { cls: 'card product-info page4' },
        { cls: 'card product-info page5' }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code. That's de helpful

Comment: Done! Hopefully you can help me but i can't find anything out of the regular in my code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by putting a listener to each tab i wanted to reset with the following code:

```
activate : function() {
    Ext.getCmp('Tab2').setActiveItem(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Tab1 is the id of your carousel, all you need to do is add a listener to your tab panel for the activeItemChange event and call a function that does this:

```
resetCarousel: function() {
    Ext.getCmp('Tab1').setActiveItem(0);
}
```

Thats pretty basic, assuming you have multiple carousels or other containers in your tab panel, you'll want to identify which tab has the specific carousel to call a reset function on. Additionally, you could use that code right in your listener function. So if you added a listener to your tabpanel, you could reset specific containers like so:

```
onTabChange: function(object, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
    console.log(value); //do this and view the console to see what the values are so you can specify them in your conditions
    if (value == "x") {
        Ext.getCmp('Tab1').setActiveItem(0);
    } else if (value == "y") {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but first of all onTabChange doesnt work. Tried it with activeitemchange, and it works to get out soem console info. The problem is that all tab changes give me the same value: `Ext.apply.create.f` So nothing happens with your code im afraid!